# Is there a way to show line numbers at end of the line in Vim

Tags: vim

I am using

```
set relativenumber
set number
```

which let's me move easily around. However, it is often hard to know the exact the line number of the object where I would like to jump to because I first need to look to the left. I feel it would be easier if I could see the line numbers also on the right hand side right because my eyes have less space to follow (maybe?). I think the ideal setting would be to show the relative/absolute line number where the `$` appears when whitespace characters are shown *and* to the left/right of the buffer. I.e.

```
  1 Random text.$1                                                                 1  
159 This is the line where the cursor is.$159                                    159
  1 Some random text.$1                                                            1
  2 More random text. Another sentence. Maybe a third one? And so on.$2            2
  3 Another line which might be quite long and my eyes focus somewhere here.$3     3
  4 More random text containing more text and more words and stuff.$4              4
```

(In this example, I would like to do `3k` but I may type `2k` or `4k` because I did not follow the correct line to the left.)

Is it possible to achieve this somehow?
Any suggestion on how to change my workflow are welcome, too.

Note: Using `cursorline` does not help as I do not seek the number of the current line.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no built-in support to your requirement. also I don't think this is easy to be done by plugin.

Maybe you could consider to change your habit/workflow. E.g.  enable the `cursorline` option, to highlight your "current" line, it may let you easier to identify which line are you on right now.

To move cursor, if you don't want to count lines, you may want to try the `EasyMotion` plugin. It is very handy plugin. However it won't replace the `hjkl ...` motions.

Comment: I can't get relative line numbers on the right but `%s/$/\=line('.')/g` will add the real line number, unindented, at the right hand edge

Comment: @Steve what you are doing is changing the buffer. ok say you did that, line number was added to the buffer. now in the middle somewhere of the buffer, do a `5J`, how would you maintain the line number?

Comment: Fair point. I missed where he was joining lines. Thought he was trying to move. The idea is not a useable one but possibly could be used in a plugin which I don't have the skill to write.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible, unless you modify Vim's source code in a non-trivial way, or work around with kludges like a vertically split small scratch buffer at the side that is updated via autocmds.

Do you have `:set cursorline`? That helps (me) a lot to follow the current line, even with large window widths. Reducing those might help, too, though you have to deal with wrapping / scrolling of long lines then.

Comment: Actually, there is way to have the line numbers on the right. Use `:set rl`, but this is probably not what the OP wants.